# Can't use arrow keys on CentOS6 when interactive. Only when using SSH from remote machine

Tags: terminal

When using an interactive logon on a CentOS 6 server, using the arrow keys shows these characters: `^[[A ^[[B ^[[C ^[[D` However when I log in using SSH, I can use the arrow keys as per normal. What could the problem be and how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Do you mean you use arrow keys in vim editor?

Comment: I mean wheen i use arrows key in terminal, wheen linux is logged i login as root and there problem starts to happend.

Comment: I suspect that you're not using the bash shell, maybe: zsh or ksh. Show us the output of `ps -p $$` or `echo $SHELL`?